# how to extract 9 and 90 from 2.9 and 2.09 i.e getting decimal part with digits equal to largest no. of digits after dicimal

Tags: c++

how to extract 9 and 90 from 2.9 and 2.09 i.e getting decimal part with digits equal to largest no. of digits after dicimal

Comment: Got any code for us?

Comment: you code some exe to do it :)

Comment: i tried and did it with strings

Comment: edit your post to include that, explain why what you did doesn't do what you want, and you might get an answer this way. The way you posted it, looks like you're just hoping we'll write your code for you

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity. I don't understand what you mean by "extract 90" from "2.09".

Comment: yp that is what i had in mind

Comment: well that's not what Stack Overflow is. We are here to HELP with problems in your code, not completely write it for you.

Comment: Your question makes 0 sense. Please reword. "Getting decimal part with digits equal to largest no. of digits after dicimal" --> makes no sense.

Comment: we have 2.9 and 2.09 numbers after dicimals 0.9 and 0.09 larger no. of digits after dicimal 09 i.e 2 so we should have 2 digits when we change int integers ie .9 changes to 90 and 0.09 remains 09 ie 9

Comment: I understand English may not be your first language, but seriously, try a little harder to communicate the problem. I still only have a vague idea of what you want to do (separate the fractional part of a floating point number from the integer part?)

Comment: i want to optimize my code but the compiler cant make a difference between 9 and 09

Comment: yes that is what i was thinking

Comment: If you're using `float`, 2.09 is actually 2.0899999141693115234375, so you would probably wind up with 5734325113961419999980 rather than 90.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm for you:
1. Split the floating point into the integer component and the fractional component.
There are functions in the math library to help here.

2. Multiply the fractional part by some power of 10 to get your digits.
   For example, to get 4 digits, you would multiply .14159263 by 10000 to get 1415.9263.
3. Truncate the fractional part by converting floating point to integer.
   You may want to review the math library for functions that will do this.

Comment: i did split the floating point and wanted to convert them to integers like .09 to 9 and 0.9 to 90 as for two no. we can do it easily but for many no converting them like that, depending on no of digits in the floating point with most digits thats my problem

Comment: You will need to come up with a rule or function that determines how many decimal digits to convert.  You can't always rely on searching for the digit 0, because that may be a significant digit in the fractional part of the floating point number.

Comment: the rule is find most no of digits after dicimal for the given situation say n and multiply all by 10^n